# Woocommerce subscriptions - How to get the trial period in days of a subscription product in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am iterating through all subscription products that appear because of `[products]` shortcode and I want to do a task if the subscription product has n number of trial period days. How can I get this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one.

```
if ( class_exists( 'WC_Subscriptions_Product' ) && 
    WC_Subscriptions_Product::get_trial_length( $product_id ) > 0 ) {
    //do a thing here
}
```

**Reference:**
[WC_Subscriptions_Product](https://github.com/wp-premium/woocommerce-subscriptions/blob/master/includes/class-wc-subscriptions-product.php)